# Convert MongoDB Json to C# Class

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I've result from MongoDB called by "mongoDBResult"

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57e8e914c2ef164375bc0957"
    },
    "user": "456"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57e8ea87bd966f3e6de5361b"
    },
    "user": "admin"
}]
```

And my Class define

```
public class Id
{
    public string oid { get; set; }
}

public class User
{       
    public Id _id { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
}
```

But when i use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject like this :

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(mongoDBResult);
```

I can get value of user name , and i want to get value of Id.oid but still always null

Anyone can help me how to convert from MongoDB to C# Class with perfect way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

**JOSN**:

```
"$oid": "57e8e914c2ef164375bc0957"
```

**CODE**:

```
public string oid { get; set; }
```

In JSON you have `$oid` in code `oid`

You can try:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$oid")]
public string oid { get; set; }
```

Or you can change JSON, if you can.

Comment: @EddyLee I'm glad that I helped. Mark reply as an answer ;-)

Comment: @EddyLee if the answer helped you, mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
 Test routes_list = 
      (Test)json_serializer.DeserializeObject("{ \"test\":\"some data\" }");
```

Comment: var user = (List<User>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(mongoDBResult); => still get null at Id.oid